# unable to get value from JsSuccess

Tags: playframework-2.6

I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to models.Data` error when I try to get a value from JsSuccess. What is the mistake in the following code?

```
val dataOption = request.body.validateOpt[Data]
      dataOption match {
        case dataSuccess:JsSuccess[Data] => {
          println("validated request body:" + dataSuccess) //I see this print
          val data:Data = dataSuccess.value //PROGRAM THROWS EXCEPTION HERE
          println("received data:" + data +", "+data.mydata)
```

I receive the following data
`{"data":{"field1":"d","field2":"d","field3":["d"],"field4":["d"],"field5":[1],"field6":"d","field7":"d"}}`

The `JsValue.validateOpt` successfully casts the data

`validated request body:JsSuccess(Some(Data(MyData(None,d,List(d),List(1),d,Set(d),d,d))),/my-data)`

Then when I try to get the data, the program throws an exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to models.Data`

```
val data:Data = dataSuccess.value //PROGRAM THROWS EXCEPTION HERE
              println("received data:" + data +", "+data.mydata)
```

The model class is

```
case class Data(myData:MyData)

case class MyData (field1: Option[UUID],
                              field2: String,
                              field3: List[String],
                              field4: Seq[Byte],
                              field5: String,
                              field6: Set[String],
                              field7: String,
                              field8:String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case dataSuccess:JsSuccess[Data]` should be `questionSuccess:JsSuccess[Option[Data]]` because `validateOpt[T]` returns `Option[T]`